# Why is nothing being printed? C Programming

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I'm making a program that takes the characters from `congress.txt` makes them all uppercase, then "shifts them two characters", (A goes to C) (Z goes to B). But nothing is being printed, my main concern is if my arrays are being stored and passed to the different functions properly.

This is what is in `congress.txt`:

> Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition the government for a redress of grievances.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int processFile(int *store);
int cipher(int *store, int *code);
int outputCode(int *code);

int main(void){
    int store[300], code[300], i;

    processFile(store);
    cipher(store, code);
    outputCode(code);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void processFile(int *store){
    int i, a = 0;
    FILE *f = fopen("congress.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; a != EOF;){
        fscanf(f, "%c", &a);        //store character in a
        if (a <= 'Z' && a >= 'A'){  //store uppercase letters
            store[i] = a;
            i++;
        }
        if (a <= 'z' && a >= 'a'){  //store lowercase letters as uppercase
            store[i] = a - 32;
            i++;
        }
    }
    i++;
    store[i] = '\0';
}

void cipher(int *store, int *code){
    int i;

    for (i = 0; store[i] != 0; ++i){
        if (store[i] <= 'X' && store[i] >= 'A'){    //tests to see if the letter is between A and X
            code[i] = (char)(store[i] + 2);         //shifts letter by two characters
        }
        if (store[i] >= 'Y' && store[i] <= 'Z'){
            code[i] = (char)(store[i] - 24);        //shifts Y and Z to A or B respectively
        }
    }
}

void outputCode(int *code){
    int i, a, b;
    for (a = 0; code[a] != 0; ++a){
        if (!(a % 50)){                             //makes a newline every 50 characters
            printf("\n");
        }
        for (b = 0; code[a] != 0 && b <= 5; ++b){   //prints chunks of 5 characters then makes a space
            printf("%c", code[a]);
        }
        printf(" ");
    }

}
```

Comment: you should probably explicitly put a terminating `'\0'` at the end of your string in `processFile`...

Comment: You should probably change your `return;` to `return 0;` or something since the function must return an `int`.  In addition, your other functions are also supposed to return a value.  If you don't need that, change the return type to `void`.  I recommend compiling your code with all warnings enabled to detect these trivial errors early.

Comment: Floris would the edit I'm about to make do that?

Comment: Please take heed of the comments from the last time you posted this code... the `a != EOF` condition is completely wrong. This loop will never terminate.

Comment: oh sorry matt I thought I fixed it by making a an int, i'll check out the last post

Comment: You're reading a single character with `fscanf` but reading it into an int. That's not generally going to work very well. Why not use `fgetc` which returns the int you are expecting.

Comment: When EOF is reached, `fscanf(f, "%c", &a)` does *not* set `a` to `EOF` (in fact, `a` is not supposed to be an `int` at all).  Rather, it will *return* `EOF` from the function call.  Therefore, you need to explicitly check the return value of `fscanf` in order to break the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code - many of which your compiler will complain about.

To start - you don't have return values for functions that are declared `int`. Just make them `void`, or return something.

Second - you declare `int a;` but proceed to use it like a `char`. Declare it how you use it.

Third - testing for end of file is done with `feof(f)` not `a != EOF`.

Fourth - when you output your code you need to increment `a`, otherwise you get the same value five times:

```
VVVVVV JJJJJJ KKKKKK UUUUUU KKKKKK UUUUUU UUUUUU
```

etc.

Fifth - your printing routine doesn't guarantee it will stop - if you have a single `'\0'` followed by other garbage, you will print more garbage (unless it happens on a multiple of 5). You need to pad your cipher with zeros.

So - working code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int processFile(int *store);
int cipher(int *store, int *code);
int outputCode(int *code);

int main(void){
    int store[300], code[300], i;

    processFile(store);
    cipher(store, code);
    outputCode(code);
    printf("\n=====\n\n");
    return 0;
}

int processFile(int *store){
    int i;
    char a = 0;
    FILE *f = fopen("congress.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; !feof(f) && i<299;){
        fscanf(f, "%c", &a);        //store character in a
        if (a <= 'Z' && a >= 'A'){  //store uppercase letters
            store[i] = a;
            i++;
        }
        if (a <= 'z' && a >= 'a'){  //store lowercase letters as uppercase
            store[i] = a - 32;
            i++;
        }
    }
    store[i]='\0';
    return 0;
}

int cipher(int *store, int *code){
    int i;

    for (i = 0; store[i] != 0; ++i){
        if (store[i] <= 'X' && store[i] >= 'A'){    //tests to see if the letter is between A and X
            code[i] = (char)(store[i] + 2);         //shifts letter by two characters
        }
        if (store[i] >= 'Y' && store[i] <= 'Z'){
            code[i] = (char)(store[i] - 24);        //shifts Y and Z to A or B respectively
        }
    }
    for(; i<300; i++) code[i]=0; // pad with zeros
    return 0;
}

int outputCode(int *code){
    int i, a, b;
    for (a = 0; code[a] != 0; ++a){
        if (!(a % 50)){                             //makes a newline every 50 characters
            printf("\n");
        }

        for (b = 0; code[a] != 0 && b <= 5; ++b){   //prints chunks of 5 characters then makes a space
            printf("%c", code[a++]);
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I also was able to notice another small error, although it's an important one. In outputCode the first for loop should not be incremented upon completion because then it skips a value of a.

Comment: @shanebird - glad you got it working and noticed the additional bug. That's how programming works - you fix one thing, another shows up...